# Avoiding repetitive job when dealing with many variables

Tags: c#, variables

I'm looking for some advices how to deal with similar example problem:

```
string A;
string B;
string C;
string D;
...

void Initialize()
{
    A = someObject.A.ToString();
    B = someObject.B.ToString();
    C = someObject.C.ToString("F");
    D = someObject.D.ToString();
    ...
}
```

My class has a lot of numeric variables and I need to pass their values to these strings easily for large quantity of such variables. Let's say it is RPG stats based game and a lot of stats, factors etc. play here a role. Managing such a many variables by copy pasting is a pain.

**Question**: how can I simplify work with lots of variables.
I would like to know some solutions for this problem since I don't have any experience with it and I don't know anyone or any source to search for a solutions.

I personally thought about using some kind of structure, dicitonary or database.

EDIT: To be precise I've created a class called Character and it has a lot of properties like xp, life, gold etc. Now I want to do a GUI using class called Label that draw text on the screen, so I'm coding GUI class containing Label objects that on various events will react accordingly. For example I need to assign at the beginning to my labels specified text like:

```
Label life, gold, xp, etc;
life.text = Character.instance.Life.ToString();
gold.text = Character.instance.Gold.ToString();
xp.text = Character.instance.XP.ToString();
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatize"?

Comment: If there is no truly repetitive behavior (to be modeled in a loop), you're pretty much stuck with what you have.

Comment: Have you looked into Dependency Injection?

Comment: Did you consider using .net arrays or lists? Like `string[] strings = new string[]{someObject.A.ToString(), someObject.B.ToString() };`

Comment: By automatize I understand that my class have a lot of numeric variables and I need to pass their values to these strings easily for large quantity of such variables. Let's say it is RPG stats based game and a lot of stats, factors etc. play here a role. Managing such a many variables by copy pasting is a pain, so I would like to know some solutions for this problem since I don't have any experience with it and I don't know anyone or any source to search for a solutions. I personally thought about using some kind of structure, dicitonary or database.

Comment: @MichałSokołowski, added your comment into the question body, to make it more explicit

Comment: How many variables are we talking here?

Comment: @Tdorno Over a dozen.

Answer (score 0):

You should include more details in this question, what you exactly want to achieve.

From the information you provided, I assume you want to read the properties of someObject dynamically, execute ToString() on them and assign its value to some variables. That is a typical reflection assignment. You might want to read [a chapter covering reflection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If the assumption above is correct, you could do the following:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // We access the type information via reflection. What properties your someObject has?
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = someObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            // we get the value of the property, described by propertyInfo, from our someObject 
            object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(someObject, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                // do your special type handling here and execute ToString()
                if(value.GetType() == typeof(int))
                    propertyValues[propertyInfo.Name] = ((int)value).ToString("F");
                if(value.GetType() == ...)
                else
                    propertyValues[propertyInfo.Name] = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        // so if your someObject had a property A you can access it as follows:
        string A = propertyValues["A"];

        // or you loop the dictionary and do some suff with it (which makes much more sense):
        foreach(var keyValuePair in propertyValues)
            Console.WriteLine("Property {0} = {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
```

Comment: I won't downvote this, but I think it's potentially very misleading to suggest reflection as a solution here without knowing the OP's requirements. There's almost certainly a better design-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard for us to say without seeing your exact design/requirements, but a simple way to do this which handles many situations is to store the object itself, rather than copying its properties or fields.

For example, in your version you might have:

```
private int A;
private string B;
private double C;

public void Initialize(DataObject data)
{
    A = data.A;
    B = data.B;
    C = data.C;
}

public void DoSomething() //Just an arbitrary method using the data
{
    return B + " " + A.ToString();
}
```

Whereas, you could more simply do:

```
private DataObject _data;

public void Initialize(DataObject data)
{
    _data = data;
}

public void DoSomething() //Just an arbitrary method using the data
{
    return _data.B + " " + _data.A.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the values get into 'someObject', a first step into having less code would be to define the properties to be String, doing the conversion from int to String in the get accessor method.  Even though this just moves the ToString() to a different location, it will reduce the code each time you go to get the value.

Comment: Normally you don't have to call `ToString` very often anyway. With most designs, it's going to be simpler to just store the raw values than the `ToString`ed versions

Comment: I would still store them internally as an int and simply do ToString() on the get accessor method.  Another (ugly) option would be to store them as an int and use the Java-ish method of two different accessor methods: one for int and another for String.